# Display ony 1 button of paypal

Tags: checkout, paypal, magento2.3.1

Magento: 2.3.1

There are 2 buttons at checkout. I want to display only 1 button.

How can I?

[image]

Comment: which one do you want to display?

Comment: It will be great if you show how to hide/remove any button.

Comment: Why do you need the paypal method then? If you remove the paypal button. 
The credit option can be removed through configuration from admin.

Comment: By which option through configuration, I can remove only 1 button(credit option)?

Comment: Yes. Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Paypal Configure > Advertise Paypal Credit > Checkout Cart Page > Display > No. Removing the other one makes no sense, why use the payment method if you want to make unusable?

Comment: There is no any option/tab/menu/selection like "Checkout Cart Page" in Paypal Configure.

Answer (score 0):

We manually forced the PayPal Credit button to hide with a plugin:

```
<?php
/** Disable PayPal credit */
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Config
{
    public function afterIsMethodAvailable(\Magento\Paypal\Model\Config $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($subject->getMethodCode()==="paypal_express_bml"){
            return 0;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```